# XML RPC wordpress Anonymous Comments Posting

Tags: c#, wordpress, xml-rpc

i am posting comments on my blog it works fine but there is one problem that i cannot post anonymous comments using XML-RPC by alexjamesbrown

instead of comment author there is name of admin

here is my code

```
var wrapper = new WordPressWrapper(textblogUrltemp + "/xmlrpc.php", adminunUser, adminPass);
                var post = new Post();
                post.title = toPost.VideoTitle;
                post.dateCreated = Convert.ToDateTime(toPost.PostingDateTime);
                post.description = toPost.VideoCode;
              post.postid =  wrapper.NewPost(post, true);

 var comment = new Comment();

                    var wrap =new  WordPressWrapper(textblogUrltemp + "/xmlrpc.php", adminunUser, adminPass);

                    comment.author = videoComments.userName;
                    comment.author_email = videoComments.email;
                    comment.content = videoComments.Comment;
                    wrap.NewComment(post.postid, comment);
```

Comment: does this work for anonymous commenting, or just for the admin?

Comment: Yes it works for anonymous comments too. but you have to make few changes to the wordpress files for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it

```
var wrap =new  WordPressWrapper(textblogUrltemp + "/xmlrpc.php", "", "");
```

also you need to modify the `class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php` file and in newComment function allow the anonymous comments

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this working for [WP Remote Control](http://www.wpremotecontrol.com/). Very bad idea to unlock anonymous posting through XMLRPC. You can get flooded by Spam as anyone can do it.

The secret is to post the comment and edit it. Two requests but you're safe. There's a single method that does it in my class. Regards.

**BTW**: *My class is PHP. I have it written in C++ too but it's too dependent to my C++ library to publish.*

Comment: Lack of sleep causes lack of brain-finger-keyboard coordination :) Fixed it, thanks.